# Google search results in python not retrieving requested number of results

Tags: python, google-search

I am trying to get 100 urls of websites based on a google search term. However, when I run the code below, only 79 urls are found. Why is it not getting 100? When i google it manually, 6 million results come up

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from googlesearch import search  

# Search Google and get links

# to search 
query = "Parking space problem google scholar"

urls = []

urlcounter = 0
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=100, stop=None, pause=2): 
    print(urlcounter)
    print(j)
```

Comment: Maybe that query only has 79 hits?  Tell us why you think it should have 100.

Comment: @JohnGordon when i google it manually, 6 million results come up

Comment: Are you specifying `co.in` as the top level domain in your manual query?

Comment: When I copied your code, it failed on `from googlesearch import search` Maybe you are using the old version?

Comment: @JohnGordon Looks like I wasn't. But when I do, I still get 1000+ results. I am entering "Parking space problem google scholar site:co.in" into the google search bar to do this.

Comment: @kate-melnykova That line should work if before running you do "pip install google"

Comment: Are you sure that `site:co.in` and `tld="co.in"` mean the same thing?

Comment: That's what I found [here](https://www.lifewire.com/restrict-search-to-specific-domains-1616500)